# How to create form field for multiple models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tried to figure this out on my own but stumped -

I'm working on a crm project to learn Django and have gotten stuck trying to incorporate activities between a user and client. Specifically, I'm trying to make it possible to record an email interaction and to have the from/to fields reference either a user or client model. So essentially an email can be recorded as either from a user to client or vice versa. The next part would be to allow for multiple clients or users to be tagged in the correct fields of this interaction.

I've tried incorporating the to and from fields as models so that they can use the GenericForeignKey class like so:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class EmailTo(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type')

class EmailFrom(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type')

class EmailActivity(Activity):
    emailto = models.ForeignKey(EmailTo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    emailfrom = models.ForeignKey(EmailFrom, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to represent that on a form. I thought maybe I could use a union to combine two queries into one field using a ModelMultipleChoiceField:

```
class EmailActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emailto = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Client.objects.all().union(User.objects.all()), 
        label="To")
    emailfrom = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset= Client.objects.all().union(User.objects.all()), 
        label="From")
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = EmailActivity
        exclude = '__all__'
```

but see now that this is not possible since the queries are not the same size.

I'm starting to think I need to go back to my user models and make users and clients inherit from one "Person" model or something similar. Wanted to check here first though to see if I was possibly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

you better write your own manual form

```
class EmailActivityForm(forms.Form):
    emailto = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Client.objects.all().union(User.objects.all()), label="To")
    emailfrom = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset= Client.objects.all().union(User.objects.all()), label="From")
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

and keep going with all the other fields left.

by the way, the forms.ModelForms is made for a single model, not multiple